# Android Studio - Resources Menu

Tags: android-studio, android-resources

I am new to android Studio. I have placed a textView widget on my canvas.

I am following a tutorial which states I can now double-click on this widget which should bring up the "Resources Menu" - this doesn't happen however.

The end goal is to extract a String resource using the Resources Menu and automatically place it in strings.xml.

Can anybody shed any light on how I will get this menu up?

GF

Comment: Your question does not provide all the information required to answer. When you say, 'placed a textview widget on my canvas'. are you talking about using **Android Layout editor** to do the above operation ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to create a string resource for text used inside a textView is to switch to the Text format of the Layout.  You can switch between the Design and Text view using the tabs at the bottom of the layout.

Then, put the cursor on the string you want to replace with an ID, click ALT+ENTER, then Enter again to "Extract string resource":

[image: extract]

That will bring up the properties of the string resource:

[image: resource]

There, you can add the "Resource Name".  Once you do that, the string inside the xml will be replaced by its ID:

```
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hellostring" />
```

And the value of the string will now be in the /res/values/strings file, like

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hellostring">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Good answer and thanks. That will do it for me. I would like to know why I can't do it as per the tutorial instructions by double-clicking on the widget - must be a previous version of AS?

Comment: Perhaps it's an older version of AS?  I see when I double-click on the textView, it just brings up a properties menu.  That menu does have an ID, but it's an ID for the whole textView, not just for the string itself, so that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

yes the correct answer is "Then, put the cursor on the string you want to replace with an ID, click ALT+ENTER, then Enter again to "Extract string resource":"